# Unable to run mvn clean install on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: path, macintosh, maven

I am using `maven-3.1.1` along with eclipse neon for RCP and `jdk-7`. I am running into the following issue -
Error with Maven command: mvn clean install 
Problem running the Maven command because the process is 'null'.  Is Maven installed correctly and located on your PATH?

Running `mvn version` on terminal gives:

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 10:22:22-0500)
Maven home: /Users/lnoob/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

`echo`ing the PATH gives:

/Users/lnoob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/lnoob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/Users/lnoob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/lnoob/.rvm/bin:/Users/lnoob/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Comment: Seems like an issue with maven eclipse plugin. I was able to run the command on the terminal.